# ActiveAdmin member_action gives 401 Unauthorized response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I am building a rails app using active_admin 0.5.1.

In app/admin/plays.rb I defined an admin resource like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Play do

  member_action :upload, :method => :post do
    ...
  end

  def index
    ...
  end

end
```

Note that I added a non-standard upload-action as described here: http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html

Now whenever I call the index action, everything works just fine. When I do post to the member action :upload though, I get 401 response:

```
Started POST "/admin/plays/1/upload.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-13 18:46:36 +0100
Processing by Admin::PlaysController#upload as JS
  Parameters: {...}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  AdminUser Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms
```

Furthermore after getting this error, the admin user is logged out.

What am I missing here? I was expecting that actions defined via member_action work just like the standard actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason.

`"WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity"` is kind of a give-away.

You need to add the authenticity_token as a param to the ajax upload request to make Devise happy.

I still wish Devise would have given some more detailed hint on what happened in detail.